# Convert the contents of a logfile to a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, logging

I have a log file in this format:

```
 2022-08-03T16:41:50.109Z [INFO]  one line
 line breaks must be allowed
 2022-08-03T16:41:50.109Z [INFO]  other line
 2022-08-03T16:44:40.109Z [ERROR]  hello
```

That i want to convert to a JSON array like this:

```
[{
"date": "ISO DATE",
"level": "INFO",
"message": "one line\nline breaks must be allowed"
},
...
]
```

I am implementing it myself but isn't there a js lib that already solves that problem ?

Comment: Such questions are off-topic on SO.  Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to have pure javascript implementation, you can parse logs yourself using regex.

The biggest challenge is to parse multiline message. However you can split by regex on timestamp + level format and keep everything else as a message.

Example implementation:

```js
const data = `
     2022-08-03T16:41:50.109Z [INFO]  one line
     line breaks must be allowed
     2022-08-03T16:41:50.109Z [INFO]  other line
     2022-08-03T16:44:40.109Z [ERROR]  hello
    `.trim()

const dataParts = data.split(/(?:\n|^)\s*(\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+Z) \[(\w+)\]/).slice(1)
const parsed = []

while (dataParts.length > 0) {
  const [date, level, message] = dataParts.splice(0, 3)

  parsed.push({
    date,
    level,
    message: message.split(/\n/).map(v => v.trim()).join('\n')
  })

}

console.log(parsed)
```